# how to delete multiple directory using node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory

I was successful in creating multiple folders but when I am deleting them, it is giving an error. I am a complete beginner to Node js.

// creating multiple folders

```
let fs=require("fs");
 for(let i=2;i<=10;i++)
    {
    let dirName=`Directory-${i}`;
    fs.mkdirSync(dirName);
    fs.writeFileSync(dirName+"\\"+"readme.md",`file for ${dirName}`);
    }
```

//deleting folders

```
 for(let i=2;i<=10;i++)
{
let dirName=`Directory-${i}`;
let content=fs.readdirSync(dirName);
for(let j=0;j<content.length;j++){
    fs.unlinkSync(dirName+"\"+content[i]));
}
fs.rmdirSync(dirName);
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67649206/edit) your question to include the full error message and stack trace.

Comment: I don't know what is the error (you shold add it to this question) but in unlinkSync is a bug in the path. You have to escape backslash like in writeFileSync or change to a single quota.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small mistake in the **deleting folders** code which has nothing to do with Node.js.

Instead of using `i`, you have to use the counter of the inner loop i.e. `j`.
Also, you have to use `\\` instead of `\` or else it considers `\"` as escape character.

```
fs.unlinkSync(dirName + "\\" + content[j])
```